# setTimeout("fn(x)") doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I have a timer function which alerts a text 'hello, welcome' in a pop up for every 2 seconds. Also I have a function to clear the timer interval so as to stop the pop up at 10th second.

The pop up box showing is stopped when I use the clearInterval function line as

```
setTimeout(function() {clearInterval(x); },10000);
```

But the pop up box showing is not stopped when I use the settimeout function as

```
setTimeout("clearInterval(x);",10000);
```

However If I use settimeout function to display a pop up by defining the builtin function directly as  `setTimeout("alert('hello, welcome');",2000); // works properly`

Can you please explain why the settimeout function behaves differently for the above two lines. Please find my code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' >
function testclear()
{
    var x = setInterval("alert('hello, welcome');",2000);
    setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(x); },10000);

   // setTimeout("clearInterval(x);",10000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='txt' onchange='testclear()' />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

> But the pop up box showing is not stopped when I use the settimeout function as

```
setTimeout("clearInterval(x);",10000);
```

That is because when you eval that string, the variable 'x' has not been properly captured. It will probably point to `window.x` (and not your local variable that holds the interval timer id).

Whereas the closure in the working example has captured the proper `x`.

One more reason to avoid `eval`.

You don't have this problem (yet) with your alert, because it does not reference any variables, but I suggest you also change it to closure ("function") form.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that when you specify a string for the first parameter of `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, it will be executed with `eval` at the specific time/interval. Because of that, it is run in the global scope. In your case, `x` is not available in the global scope...it's a local variable scoped inside of the `testclear` function. Passing a function as the first parameter to `setInterval` or `setTimeout` secures the scope you were originally working with (inside the `testclear` function).

Alternatively, yet not preferably, I believe you could do this:

```
setTimeout("clearInterval(" + x + ");",10000);
```

But note that this concatenation may be different or not possible in other situations (other method calls)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `x` is local to the function `testclear()`. When you pass function to setTimeout, it will get the same scope as the one it was written in, thus `x` will be recognized.

When you pass string literal, it will be evaluated but the scope is lost.

It will also "work" if `x` will be global variable, however it's not a good practice.

Answer (score -1):

Working Example **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eFFaM/1/)** 
I have customised your code and it works fine.

1. Make x variable global.
2. `var t= setTimeout(' clearInterval(x);' ,1501);` set temp variable to catch setTimeout ,it is semantics to follow.